# MongoDB complaining about SSL handshake when SSL connection attempt is not being made

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, http, ssl

I've tried using both the official mongo Docker image as well as khezen/mongo, and I get the same error message when I try to make an unencrypted HTTP connection:

```
AssertionException handling request, closing client connection: 17133 SSL handshake requested, SSL feature not available in this build
```

That's the message from khezen/mongo.  The official mongo image gives a slightly different error:

```
AssertionException handling request, closing client connection: 17132 SSL handshake received but server is started without SSL support
```

And when the official mongo image is started from a docker-compose.yml with a custom command (`mongod --sslMode allowSSL --sslPEMKeyFile /data/db/mongodb.pem`):

```
SSL: error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request
```

Now, this is all while trying to make the following request from Postman:

Mode: POST

URL: http://localhost:27017/lasdf?client=asdf

Data payload:

```
{
    "gargen": "flagren",
    "jiminy": {
        "crickets": 1,
        "isChirping": false
    },
    "blargen": "fargle",
    "_id": "a96c2a4ec6fb4a8dbe2305687eb0e50b"
}
```

Interestingly, when I change the '`http`' to '`https`' I get no error message, but also no response, and of course the database is not changed.

Stranger still, I *am* able to access the database via the `mongo-express` docker image.  Its default configuration does not do HTTPS requests to mongodb, because when I change my custom command to '`--sslMode requireSSL`' it fails to connect.

The version of MongoDB installed in the container is 3.4.2.

Comment: I just tested the 3.2 and 3.0 tags of mongo official, and got the same response.

Answer (score -3):

This particular error does not create any issue as such.
Tried hitting with the correct port on Postman and the server is accepting the requests.
You can ignore the error